# Old British comic story about a mountain that's really a giant slow creature

Tags: story-identification, comics

Once more I'm in the world of British comics from the 1960's/1970's... Hotspur, Rover, Beezer, Topper, Victor etc.

This was one that went on for a few months.

A small town (maybe in Wales but I'm not sure) has a mountain range nearby, including one that's slightly darker than the others. Geologists or miners start digging at a side of it one day and then all stand back in awe. A few hundred yards away some sections of rock crumble away and a large eye is glaring out at them.

There are shenanigans for a while as scientists are helicoptered in but by the time they arrive the beastie is slowly moving, I think towards the town.
Herds of farm animals disappear but I can't remember how it moves fast enough to catch them.

The army rigs up a defensive live and use mortars to try and stop it but it keeps moving. I think it can do like an extending mouth (Alien Xenomorph!) and gets some soldiers yum yum.

Update!!! I just got a FB messenger from an old friend in Australia, he says the comic strip story title was very simply 'The Mountain That Moved'..... I've done a search online but I can't find it

Comment: Very nice ! I think I vaguely remember that one, but I don't remember where I saw it, alas !!

Comment: It sounds like the sort of thing that would be in 2000 AD, though I read 2000 AD in the 70s and I don't remember a story like that.

Comment: I think it was the late eighties before I ever looked at 2000 AD. This was deffo a lot earlier when I was still a schoolboy

Comment: You should be fine posting that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely definitely "The Mountain That Moved". I've looked for references on and off for years but never found anything. This is the first time anything vaguely relevant has come up.  Usually reminded of it driving up to Scotland. That said, pretty sure it was set in Wales.

Probably 55 to 60 years ago as I would have been in my early teens, perhaps a bit younger. The story line as described is much as I remember it, I just can't recall how it ended.

Would most likely have been in the Eagle, Victor or Hotspur. Certainly one that had written stories as well as cartoon strips.

Comment: Per my objection to the answer below, In the absence of any significant detail, I don't think that marking this as accepted is a wise decision. It'll simply encourage people to pass it over.

Comment: Notably, this answer doesn't contain anything that's not already in the question.

Comment: @Valorum: my post effectively ruled out 2000 AD and put a timeline on the story. IMO that was intended to be helpful. If you consistently knock contributors' input, I can't see the use, value or enjoyment of being involved with this site.

Comment: OP already ruled out 2000AD in the comments.